# Can a file based CacheDependency adversely affect performance?

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, caching

I'm trying to make an architectural decision to ease development, and want to know if anyone could provide insight how much performance overhead is necessary to institute a file based CacheDepdency in .NET?

Currently, my design approach is to segment our Javascript-based functionality into separate files for each piece of logic for maintainability/readability reasons.  At runtime, I am merging and gzip compressing all the files into a single include.   Additionally, I am using a file based CacheDependency for each logic block and on subsequent requests I am rebuilding the cache when any of those files change.

Is there a significant performance impact for using this approach?  If there are 30 files in the CacheDepdency, does this run significantly slower than say 2 or 3 files, or is this only milliseconds of difference?

Answer (score 2):

The difference would be negligible.

But the real question should be 'Why are you changing files on a deployed/released website?'.

In my opinion, it would make more sense to keep your scripts separated as you have them for DEVELOPMENT and when test/staging/release time comes around have a build script that 1) concatenates your JS files, 2) compresses them with some JavaScript compressor/optimizer -- for debugging purposes you can skip this step -- 3) serve the single static JS file and let your web server handle the GZip/caching.